# How do I defined a method bounded type on another bounded type?

Tags: java, generics

I want to define a method that defines its types like this:

`List<R> toList(JsArray<T> array)`

such that T is bounded such that it is both:

- `T extends SomeClass`, and
- `T extends R`

I've tried things like this, to no avail:

`<R, T extends R & SomeClass> List<R> toList(JsArray<T> array)`

(For the curious, this is to be able to use [GWT Overlay Types with Interfaces](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html))

Comment: em... so R will have the constraint of being an interface only implicitly. i don't think java type system can be smart like this.

Comment: also, if you extends class, it should appear at the first place: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: Building on HuStmpHrrr's comment, unless `R` is an interface this is not possible. Java does not support multiple inheritance, i.e. a Java class cannot directly extend from more than one class (but it can extend a class and implement an interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear this does not work.
The correct syntax would be

```
<R, T extends R & SomeClass> List<R> toList(JsArray<T> array)
```

But this will give you the following error message

> Cannot specify any additional bound SomeClass when first bound is a type parameter

I do not see how you could make it work to enforce both constraints.

Comment: I fear you are correct.  Just not possible other than using some unchecked code.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
<T extends SomeClass> List<? super T> toList(JsArray<T> array)
```

EDIT:

I think I see your use case.  From comments, you want to specify the return type so you don't have an unchecked cast.

But you don't actually pass anything in to tell the method what to create.  Since I could always call toList() with `R = T`, the only thing you could do that always works (for all `R super T`) is to return a `List<T>`, which makes the `R` parameter unnecessary...  but that's not what you want.

You have to pass something in to tell the method what kind of object to instantiate.  Usually we could to that like:

```
<R, T extends SomeClass> List<R> toList(JsArray<T> array, Class<R> cls)
```

and call it like

```
toList(arrayIHave, WhatIWant.class)
```

Now this will work, but you will complain that it has error conditions, because the "`T extends R`" constraint isn't captured.  But really, even if you add the constraint in, you'll still have error conditions.

I can use an *arbitrary* interface for `R` by making a `T` that extends `SomeClass` and implements `R`.  There is no way you can meaningfully instantiate an arbitrary interface, so for many `R,T` pairs that satisfy your constraints, you will have to return null or throw an exception or something.

No doubt there is *some* rule that dictates which R you will return, but there is no way to even think about specifying generic constraints that capture that rule, so there *will* be an unchecked conversion somewhere.  If you use a signature like this, at least you can put it inside the method instead of having warnings or annotations everywhere you use it.

Comment: Nope - I want to return a List of some _other_ interface, not the supertype T.

Comment: It does return a List of some supertype of T, like R is.    Did you want to *specify* R?  Well, maybe you do, but due to type erasure it could have no effect.

Comment: Yeah - my goal was to specify R.  I guess I didn't specify that in the question.  One work around is to even remove the `? super T`, and just carry around an `extends SomeInterface` downstream generics...but that's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: I like the solution to the higher level problem -- in the end, the answer to the generics question, like you mention as well, is that it just doesn't work.